# Contditionally preventing the reload of a controller modal when transition back to a Route

Tags: ember.js

Let's say I have a post and comment route. From the post I would like to add a comment and then navigate back to the post. If I use the default behaviour, when navigating back to the post, the post would reload the model, and overwrite changes.

The best I've come up with is adding property in the controller which the router can evaluate:

```
model:function(params){
    var c = this.controllerFor("post");     
    if (this.controller && this.controller.get("noReload"))
        return;

    Ember.run.next(function(){
        c.set("title","Hello");
    });
}
```

But this doesn't feel right. What it is the best/ember way, to implement this kind of behaviour?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AyKarsi/KVh3M/3/